# iOS приложение падает, если запускается через profile

Tags: xcode, память, отладка

Возникла проблема с отладкой в Xcode 6.3.2. Когда пытаюсь запустить приложение на устройстве из профайла, для анализа утечек памяти, то оно начинает запускаться и падает. В эмуляторе такого не происходит. Кто-нибудь решил проблему?

Comment: Уберите везде iOS Distribution и distribution provision profiles из Code Signing в Build Settings - может помочь

Comment: К сожалению не помогло...

Answer (score 1):

Удалось решить проблему!

1. В Xcode идем в меню Product->Scheme->Manage Schemes
2. Выбираем нужную схему и кликаем на кнопку "Edit"
3. В пункте Profile - Build Configuration должно быть установлено в  Debug, первоночально у меня было установлено в Release.

После изменения проблема решилась.

[image: Управление схемой]